# URL redirect/rewrite rule wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, htaccess

I am running wordpress multisite on a server. The main site is working just fine are url redirects are perfect. Say my domain is www.adeel.com and the site is run on following url www.adeel.com/area-guides. Because at www.adeel.com another site is running(not in wordpress, completely different).

**The issue**

From admin panel when I try to go to network admin dashboard it redirects me to  www.adeel.com/wp-admin/network/ and it displays URL NOT FOUND. If i type in manually www.adeel.com/area-guides/wp-admin/network/, it takes me to the network dashboard. And inside that dashboard all url starts from area-guides except when I try do something that updates that page.

**what I want**
I want to set all url which contain adeel.com/wp-admin -> adeel.com/area-guides/wp-admin

I believe by doing this it'll solve the issue.

**what else I have tried ** 
I have tried changing domain current site to 'www.adeel.com/area-guides' instead of just www.adeel.com. It appends the url but those urls are stuck in redirect loops tried several things but couldn't resolve them.

** htaccess file **

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but have you tried changing the RewriteBase to `/area-guides` ?

Comment: So, to clarify (from comments on my deleted answer) the WordPress multisite is actually installed in the document root and `/area-guides` is simply one of these sub-sites (WP multisite is not actually installed in the `/area-guides` directory - which is how I interpreted your question)? But this implies the "other site" in the document root is _intermingled_ with the WP multisite installation? How do you determine which site handles the URLs? Is the "other site" based solely on physical files/directories?

Comment: @AlexanderHolsgrove yes I have tried rewrite base. but it doesn't work and it'll not.

Comment: @MrWhite no /area-guides isn't the sub-site. the other site isn't handled from the root. there's another server handling that request. /area-guides is in root folder.

Comment: Ok now I'm confused. So, what is `/area-guides`? "the other site isn't handled from the root" - but you stated, "at www.adeel.com another site is running"?

Comment: @MrWhite I want to serve the site which is sitting at root on /area-guides because at www.adeel.com another site is running. another server is handling the requests for adeel.com and adeel.com/area-guides. if the request is for /area-guides it forward it to our wordpress directory in which site is at /. 
got it ?